# Minimum number of flips to guarantee heads

Tags: probability

This is a weird problem that popped into my head: given a fair coin, how many flips is required to guarantee heads?

If I get a tails, then another tails, and another etc., the chance of getting a heads increases every time. But there is still a small chance that I will get another tails.

This seems to imply that there is no finite number of flips to guarantee a heads. Does this mean that infinity is the correct answer (although infinity isn't a number as far as I understand) or is this question even answerable in the first place?

Comment: You can theoretically flip an infinite number of tails: there is no magical force in the universe that will guarantee you will ever flip a heads. That being said, the "probability" of flipping an infinite number of tails is $0$ -- this kind of event is called almost surely impossible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely#Tossing_a_coin

Comment: How do you know how many tails came up on the coin, *before* you started your experiment?  How does the coin know?

Comment: Correct: [infinity is not a number](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710291/does-an-equation-containing-infinity-not-equal-0-or-infinity-exist), and has no business being in computations that don't employ "limits".

Comment: After a few billion flips **and landings** with heads-down, enough material from ridges, etc., on the heads face might get worn off that it would no longer be a `fair coin`.

Comment: @imas145: you may be interested in looking into the concept of independence in statistics. Assuming a coin is flipped the same way every time, landing on tails doesn't affect the possibility of it landing on heads *or* on tails in future flips.

Comment: See also: [Gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy).

Comment: @Mazura: [Is infinity a number?](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/36298/14972)

Comment: Thank you everyone for correcting my assumption on the increasing chance of getting a heads.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee that you will get a heads ever. The chance of getting heads remains a constant 50-50 on each individual flip--flips are said to be *independent*. It is only in the aggregate of an increasing number of flips that the probability of getting a heads on *at least one* flip increases. However, while this probability increases monotonically, it never reaches 1.

Yes; it is extremely unlikely that you will get 5 million tails in a row, but it is entirely possible. You can answer a similar question if you are willing to set a tolerance. I.e. if you wanted 95% confidence that a heads will appear, then you want the probability that $N$ flips in a row are tails to be less than 5%.

The probability that $N$ flips in a row are tails is $(0.5)^N$. Computing this for different values of $N$:

\begin{array}{ll}
N & 0.5^ N \\
1 & 0.5                   \\
2 & 0.25                  \\
3 & 0.125                 \\
4 & 0.0625                \\
5 & 0.03125              
\end{array}

Therefore flipping the coin $5$ times will give you $(100 - 3.125)$% = $96.875$% confidence that a heads will appear at least once.

Answer (score 11):

Basically the  answer: "infinite" is the correct one. Moreover, you have to be careful in saying that the chance of obtaining a Head increases 'every time'. This statement is false. *Each time* the chance of obtaining a head is $1/2$. What is true is that the chance of obtaining at least a head in $n$ throws is $1-2^{-n}$. 
This probability clearly increases with $n$, but you should appreciate the difference with respect to your statement.

Answer (score 3):

> If I get a tails, then another tails, and another etc., the chance of getting a heads increases every time.

no. it's still a fair coin after you throw several tails. it's always 50% odds of heads or tails on the next throw. this is just as superstitious as thinking you're at a hot craps table at the casino.